# Datepicker get maxDate or Mindate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use serverall datepickers on a page and i set the maxDate and Mindate on different Events. In some cases (e.g. removing a period) I want to know what the max of mindate was set to on a datepicker. Is there a way to retrieve the maxDate or minDate from a datepicker by document.getElementById ($)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read the docs:

```
var minDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

Updated link on 05, Nov 2018:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate